# pyrocms hooks not working

Tags: php, cookies, hook, pyrocms

I have a case where when a user visits my site I first need to check if he is logged in and if not then check for certain cookie and I need to do this is every page and hooks seemed like the correct way for me but for some reason I can't get them to work in pyrocms, I created a user_login.php in system/cms/hooks and then added the hook in hooks.php as

`$hook['pre_controller'][] = array(
    'function' => 'read_cookie',
    'filename' => 'user_login.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);`

I logged a simple statement to check if the hook is working but I can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.